# Series of consecutive composite numbers

Tags: prime-numbers

Being given $a \in \mathbb{N}$, find the smallest $N$ such that
 $\{ N, N+1, N+2, N+3, N+4, ...., N+a\}$ are all(consecutive) composite numbers.

For example for $a=2$, $N=8$ ; for $a=4$, $N=24$.

I am looking for a general formula.

Comment: thats not a question

Comment: No general formula known. But an example of such $N$ is known.

Comment: Take $N=m!+2$ for some and that $m> a$

Comment: The numbers are tabulated at http://oeis.org/A008950 where there are some references (but no formulas, and as others have said no one knows any formulas).

Comment: Great! Thank you Gerry Myerson. You helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider the natural, classical, different, question: given any $a$, is it always possible to find a sequence of $a+1$ consecutive composite numbers ?

The answer is: it suffices to take $M=(a+1)!$ (factorial of $(a+1)$). Why that?

Thus, this constitutes a partial answer to your question: your $N$ is at most $(a+1)!+2$.

Comment: Yes. It is obvious that N=< (a+1)!+2. I am looking for the minimum. Formula or pattern?

Comment: I couldn't guess you know this result because you don't speak about it. Besides, as астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг, I am fairly certain that no formula exist for this minimum $N$.

Comment: I meant no offence. I appreciate your answer and comment. :) And thanks to астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг.